# Set file permission using octal notation in java

Tags: java, linux, posix, file-permissions

I want to create files and directories from my java code with required unix permissions. The unix permissions are taken as input from user and are given as octal number(For e.g. 02775). I found the `java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission` to be quite handy however it doesn't allow setting the setgid (+s) bit. Following code throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mode`

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> posixPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwsr-x");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(someDir, posixPermissions);
```

Also I want to avoid manually converting the octal number to posix permission string(e.g: "rwxrw-r-x"). Is there any way to do this in java apart from triggering a sub-process with chmod command ?

Comment: Numbers can be converted rather simply like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234598/how-to-convert-an-input-of-3-octal-numbers-into-chmod-permissions-into-binary . Not sure about setgid though, maybe that is just file system specific and thus something that the POSIX layer doesnt support? Also note that it you should ask ONE question per qustion ...

Comment: @GhostCat, yes it is simple to convert octal to permission string but I was hoping if some library is already taking permission as an octal number.

Comment: Asking for libraries is explicitly off topic here ;-(

Comment: The main problem is even if I convert oct to string I am not able to find any way to set the permissions bits (set user ID,  set group ID, and restricted deletion or sticky attribute) which comes from parsing the first digit of octal number. Is there any way for that ?

Comment: Here you find https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermission.html those permissions that the standard library allows you to touch. Anything beyond that is file system specific. It just seems something java doesnt care too much about see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137404 for example.